# Cant send a var to props in another component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I wanna send a var to another Component in React and get it in props. But received props is null [image][image]

Comment: I Should say Insta.js is sending props to Posts.js

Comment: why do you have a return inside your return ?

Comment: It's pretty hard to resolve this issue because the main structure is wrong here. You are returning a component inside an `onClick` which is not how it works. Try to just put `<Posts />` outside of that `onClick` and check if the props are passed down. If you want to render something with an `onClick` I would have a look at hooks

Comment: Can you create a snippet on https://codesandbox.io/ or similar and share so that we get a full picture?

Answer (score 1):

if you are importing `Posts` component you need to export it as shown below

```
function Posts(props) {
   console.log(props)
   ----
   ----
}

export default Posts; // need to add this line
```

Comment: yes i did this but in photo is not visible

Comment: @mohammadhosein change image file name, without spaces and import it. ex `sun_image.png`